# Trim the redundant data

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, morphia

I want to delete the data on the date basis(which is present inside the array). This is how my mongo document looks like.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3d94df83f68f8bf751f367"),
    "branchName" : "krishYogaCenter",
    "Places" : [ 
        "Pune", 
        "Bangalore",
        "Hyderabad",
        "Delhi"
    ],
    "rulesForDateRanges" : [ 
        {
            "fromDate" : ISODate("2019-01-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "toDate" : ISODate("2019-03-06T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "place" : "Delhi",
            "ruleIds" : [ 
                5, 
                6, 
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "fromDate" : ISODate("2019-03-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "toDate" : ISODate("2019-05-06T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "place" : "Hyderabad",
            "ruleIds" : [ 
                1, 
                2
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-28T12:31:35.694Z"),
    "updatedBy" : "Theia"
}
```

Here, if "toDate" is less than today I want to delete that object from the array "rulesForDateRanges". Searched on the google but did not get any way to do this in morphia.

If this date was not present internally in the array object then I could have used "delete document where the date is less than today". Here I want to remove that object from the array which is in no longer use, and if the array "rulesForDateRanges" becomes empty in that case only want to delete the whole document.

I am using morphia. Please suggest the way to do this in morphia or the query to do this.

Searched on google got this: We can get the document one by one from the collection using query and do UpdateOperation over that document. But here I have to perform updateOperation for each and every document.